# Duplicate Content SEO http & https

Tags: https, seo, duplicates

I have the alert of duplicate content. All the website doesn't use HTTP, only the login page and pages with contact form.

How I fix this? The solutions I found is for all the website, but, I only the login page and pages with contact form is in https and ignore the http, and the others pages, only http.

Comment: If after the https login page the user is connected in http webpage then anybody can steal the login cookie. You should think about migrate all your website to https, it's the only secure way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use
`<link rel="canonical" href="..." />`
 on all your web page available over http AND https to said which version should be indexed.

See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: You're welcome. As it solve your problem, could you validate my answer with the check mark?